# Query to get grandparents and grandkids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table `people`:

```
ID   name    surname   mother_id  father_id
--------------------------------------------
1    John    smith     null       null
2    kate    m         null       null
3    philip  smith        2         1
4    dimitr  smith        7         3
```

etc.

I tried this query.

```
SELECT 
    p.name, P.surname, 
    c.name as 'Mothers name', c.surname as 'Mothers surname',  
    gm.name as 'Grandmother name', gm.surname as 'Grandmother surname'
FROM
    dbo.people AS p
JOIN
    dbo.people AS c ON (c.mother = p.Id)
JOIN
    dbo.people AS gm ON (gm.mother = c.Id)
```

But it doesn't really return what I expected

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with `ON` clause :

```
select p.name, p.surname, 
       coalesce(pm.name, '') as mothername, coalesce(pm.surname, '') as mothersurname,
       coalesce(pf.name, '') as grandmothername, 
       coalesce(pf.surname, '') as grandmothersurname
from people p left join
     people pm
     on pm.id = p.mother_id left join -- use mother_id from people p
     people pf
     on pf.id = p.father_id; -- use father_id from people p;
```

Here is [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdinBJcHX2mWGueqrjg825/0).

Comment: Yogesh was correct about the swapping of the join columns. You can see and play around with the solution [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdinBJcHX2mWGueqrjg825/0) on db-fiddle